# Android: Single Fragment to display list and button at the same table

Tags: android, fragment

I have downloaded a sample app which has two fragments on it. The left fragment shows items and the right fragment shows contect based on which item is selected.

What I want to do is to also have a button on the left fragment which can be used to update the list that is shown. Hence why I want a list and a button to apppear on the same fragment at the same time.

Can this be done. My example code is: -

layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
              android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
              android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main activity code is: -

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

    // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first
    // fragment
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
        HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from
        // an Intent,
        // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();

        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment);

        transaction.commit();

    }
}
```

Is it possible to also have a button to appear after the R.id.fragment_container is done.

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways of doing this. The simplest way is to let the activity keep references to the fragments, and create a method in the list fragment that can be called by the other fragment through a method in the activity.

Another way of doing is via Broadcasts.

A third way of doing it is use RoboGuice and inject a class in both fragments that establishes communication between the fragments.